# Copy a range using indirect

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Looking to build a macro to copy and paste data.  The column length of the data to copy from will keep changing so I'm trying to find a way to capture this data.  I figured putting a formula directly into the sheet to put the range would be a good start, so I'm wondering how do I copy from a range that's located in my cell `N1`.

[image: cell N1]

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this code will be a good start:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    Dim rngCopy             As Excel.Range
    Dim rngPaste            As Excel.Range

    With Sheet1
        Set rngCopy = .Range(.Range("N1").Value)
        Set rngPaste = .Range("A1")
        rngCopy.Copy
        rngPaste.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
    End With
End Sub
```

This code assumes that you are copying data from the range that you specified in cell N1 and pasting it into cell A1 (you can easily modify it by changing rngPaste parameter).

Let me know if you have any questions. Take care.

Comment: Thanks Justyna, but I didn't realize that I posted my question outside of a google sheets zone, so my question didn't specify that I'm using google sheets. Not sure if you are familiar and can modify for google sheets?  Thanks, Marc

Comment: Hi Marc, Google Sheets are using Google Appscript which is not compatible with VBA (i.e. Appscript is based on javascript). There are some tips provided under this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803155/any-way-to-use-vba-on-google-spreadsheet
Unfortunately I am not familiar with Google Appscript so I suggest changing the tags for this thread (from "vba" to "appscript") or creating a separate thread and re-posting your question.

Comment: Thank you Justyna... I didnt put those tags, I guess someone who has access to did it, but it seems now I have access to create a new tag, so I removed as you suggested and added appscript as tag... hopefully I get the right help.  Much appreciated your time however. All the best! Marc